# How do I log to the SharePoint ULS logs from a Silverlight web part?

Tags: silverlight, logging, uls

I am developing a Silverlight application which is to be hosted on a sharepoint 2010 page using the out of the box Silverlight webpart control. I want to log any exceptions to the sharepoint ULS logs which arise from the silverlight webpart.

I tried using the `SharePointDiagnostics.SendClientScriptErrorReport` method. However, I am getting an error regarding client certificate.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Diagnostics service (http://YourSite/_vti_bin/Diagnostics.asmx) as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcdiagnostics.sharepointdiagnostics.sendclientscripterrorreport.aspx from any Client technology (Silverlight or Javascript), but it seems you would need to add the clientaccesspolicy.xml to allow access to the web service as explained here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx) containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
 <cross-domain-access>
   <policy>
     <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
       <domain uri="*"/>
     </allow-from>
     <grant-to>
       <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
     </grant-to>
   </policy>
 </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

in your C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 (assuming you run on port 80)

Comment: Initially had to Hard code the Credentials as it was giving me an 401 Unauthorized error . Later on it works fine and SendClientErrorReport method from the Diagnostic service seems to complete with no error but the error is not logged in the 14\Logs folder

Comment: have you tried sending logs via a Console - just to validate that indeed Logging is properly functioning.